# Tries to create file

Tags: java, file, file-io, filereader, filewriter

I wanted to create a text file to store data. The name of the text file is based on what the user typed. The code works fine but I don't know why, it create the file, but it also generates a null file automatically, but my data isn't in both of those files. Why is it? Here's my code:

```
public void setCustomerID()
{
    System.out.print("\nYou've choose to register a new customer\n");
    System.out.print("Please enter the customer's ID: ");
    custID = input.nextLine();
}

public String getCustomerID()
{
    return custID;
}

public void openInputFile()
{
    try
    {
        write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\RetailDatabase\\" + (getCustomerID()) + ".txt",true)));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error opening / creating / writing a file!");
    }
}

public void addCustomer()
{
    String firstname, lastname, sex, addrss, phoneNum, dob;
    CustomerDetails record;

    try
    {
        setCustomerID();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's first name: ");
        firstname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's last name: ");
        lastname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's gender: ");
        sex = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's address: ");
        addrss = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's phone number: ");
        phoneNum = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the customer's date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        dob = input.nextLine();
        record = new CustomerDetails(firstname, lastname, sex, addrss, phoneNum, dob);
        write.printf("\nFirst Name: %s \nLast Name: %s \nGender: %s \nAddress: %s \nPhone Number: %s \nDate Of Birth: %s",record.getFirstName(),record.getLastName(),record.getGender(),
        record.getCustAddress(),record.getPhoneNumber(),record.getDateOfBirth());
        openInputFile();
        System.out.print("Customer's details is recorded!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error writing to file!");
        return;
    }
}

public void closeInputFile()
{
    try
    {
        write.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error closing file!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to your close method also otherwise the data will not be written to the file and make sure when writing it is done in order

```
openInputFile()
// write data.....
closeInputFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to write to a file when your `write` object is `null`. You call `write.printf` first, then initialize it later after you call `openInputFile()`.

Also, as Java Devil mentioned, you neglect to close the `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

you are first writing to unopened file

```
write.printf("\nFirst Name: %s \nLast Name: %s \nGender: %s \nAddress: %s \nPhone Number: %s \nDate Of Birth: %s",record.getFirstName(),record.getLastName(),record.getGender(),
    record.getCustAddress(),record.getPhoneNumber(),record.getDateOfBirth());
```

and then opening it

```
openInputFile();
```

You should maybe call openInputFile() somewhere from outside of class, and before calling addCustomer() method.

Comment: oh yeap, I figured it out after posting this question for few minutes. thanks anyway. :)